# How to clear already sent notification message

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I've a working notifications part in my project. And I want to give user to disable notifications in app itself. Once user checks this option, I bring tile image and title to original state. Even this part works fine.
Count can be removed by sending 0,
But i didn't understand how to remove already sent message, esp:

```
<wp:BackContent> </wp:BackContent>
```

I tried sending empty message but it didn't work. Any idea, how to clear this message on tile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:
Need to send "clear", if you want to clear anything. Very intuitive but not documented well.

```
<wp:BackBackgroundImage Action=”Clear”></wp:BackBackgroundImage>

<wp:BackTitle Action=”Clear”></wp:BackTitle>

<wp:BackContent Action=”Clear”></wp:BackContent>
```

Comment: I can sense that you downvoted me, but thats okay. I updated my answer with code piece you were looking, Let me know if you still have any problem. I can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

See this post on the AppHub: [How do I reset a flipping Mango Tile after push notification?](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/86560.aspx)